# view Terraform output from module using for_each and toset

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i have a simple terraform script which makes use of a module, the script creates multiple s3 buckets:

**main.tf:**

```
variable "bucket_name"{
    type = list
    description = "name of bucket"
}

module "s3" {
    source = "../modules/s3"
    for_each = toset(var.bucket_name)
    bucket_name = "${each.key}"
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "arn" {
  description = "ARN of the bucket"
  value       = module.s3.arn
}
```

**names.tfvars:**

```
bucket_name = ["bucket-a", "bucket-b"]
```

**modules/s3/main.tf:**

```
resource aws_s3_bucket "mybucket" {
    bucket = var.bucket_name
    }
```

**modules/s3/variables.tf**

```
variable "bucket_name" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}
```

**modules/s3/outputs.tf**

```
output "arn" {
  description = "Name of the bucket"
  value       = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.arn
}
```

---

The issue i have is when i run a plan i get the following error:

```
│     │ module.s3 is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

i'm trying to access the arn of the generated buckets but unsure of where i have gone wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each`, you have to access individual instances of your module, such as `module.s3["bucket-a"].arn`.

If you want to get the **list of all ARNs** of your buckets generated by the module, then it should be:

```
output "arn" {
  description = "ARN of the bucket"
  value       = values(module.s3)[*].arn
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, im assuming if i want to pass the first arn to another resource i can use values(module.s3)[0].arn?

Comment: @user7502743 You have to use full name, `module.s3["bucket-a"].arn`. If you don't know the name, then `values(module.s3)[0].arn`