# How to use the output from a looped module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to produce results similar to this question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235845/view-terraform-output-from-module-using-for-each-and-toset). I have the following parent main.tf file

```
module "shared_services_lambdas" {
  source = "../dataLoaderLambda"
  for_each = toset(var.data_source_list)

  environment = var.environment
  lambda_name = each.value
  s3_bucket = module.bucket.shared_services_bucket
  lambda_role_arn = module.shared_services_lambda_role.role_arn
  s3_source_account = var.s3_source_account
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  vpc_subnet_ids = var.vpc_subnet_ids
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = module.bucket.shared_services_bucket

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = toset(var.data_source_list)
    content {
      lambda_function_arn = module.shared_services_lambdas[lambda_function.value].lambda_arn
      events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:Put"]
      filter_prefix       = "entitlements/data/loaders/${lower(lambda_function.value)}/"
      filter_suffix       = ".data"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [module.shared_services_lambdas]
}
```

Where I want to create a dynamic amount of lambdas (first module) and then for each lambda create a trigger in the same s3 bucket. So, I create a set of lambdas from the loop, I then want to loop through the bucket notification dynamic block and make a trigger for each of the previously created lambdas

The `main.tf` for the lambda module is:

```
locals {
  resource_map = {
    dev  = {memory = 128, tag = "latest"},
    test = {memory = 128, tag = "latest"},
    uat = {memory = 128, tag = "latest"},
    stg  = {memory = 128, tag = "latest"},
    prod = {memory = 128, tag = "latest"}
  }
}

module "shared_services_lambda_data_loader" {
  source = "../../../resource/lambda/container"
  name = "Shared-Services-${var.lambda_name}-Loader"
  description = "Data Loader for ${var.lambda_name}"
  image_url = "043594735518.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/experian/uk/consumerbureau/entitlements/dataloaders"
  image_tag = local.resource_map[var.environment].tag
  command = "Experian.UK.ConsumerBureau.Entitlements.DataLoaders.Lambda::Experian.UK.ConsumerBureau.Entitlements.DataLoaders.Lambda.V1.Loader::${var.lambda_name}"
  memory_size = local.resource_map[var.environment].memory
  role = var.lambda_role_arn

  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  vpc_subnet_ids = var.vpc_subnet_ids
}

module "shared_services_lambda_data_loader_allow_permission" {
  source = "../../../resource/lambda/permission"
  lambda_function_name = module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader.name
  statement_id = "AllowS3"
  bucket = var.s3_bucket
  principal = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  source_account = var.s3_source_account
}
```

and the `output.tf` file for the `lambda_data_loader` module is (as in the linked example):

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = values(module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader)[*]
}
```

However the following error is being thrown when trying to create the bucket notification:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../modules/resource/lambda/DataLoaderAll/main.tf line 45, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification":
  45:       lambda_function_arn = module.shared_services_lambdas[lambda_function.value].lambda_arn
    ├────────────────
    │ module.shared_services_lambdas is object with 5 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "lambda_function_arn": string required.
```

As I am feeding it a list of length 5 it looks like it isn't isolating individual elements in the list rather the whole list.

EDIT:

the `output.tf` file for the `../../../resource/lambda/container` module is (this is where the ARN value is coming from):

```
output "arn" {
  description = "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) identifying your Lambda Function."
  value       = aws_lambda_function.container.arn
}

output "invoke_arn" {
  description = " The ARN to be used for invoking Lambda Function from API Gateway - to be used in aws_api_gateway_integration uri."
  value       = aws_lambda_function.container.invoke_arn
}

output "qualified_arn" {
  description = " The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) identifying your Lambda Function Version (if versioning is enabled via publish = true)."
  value       = aws_lambda_function.container.qualified_arn
}

output "name" {
  description = "The name of the lambda function."
  value       = var.name
}
```

Comment: This `value = values(module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader)[*]` will return a list anyway. Do you have any output defined in `../dataLoaderLambda` module that would provide the Lambda ARN?

Comment: @MarkoE the output.tf file I have included in my question are for the dataLoaderLambda module. I've updated the question to make it a bit more clear. What I want is to be able to access each element of the dataLoaderLambda module output in the bucket notification resource I build after

Comment: Ok then, so you are using nested modules? For this to work, you have to have an output defined in the `../../../resource/lambda/container` module. Do you have it there?

Comment: @MarkoE I have added the output of this file to the bottom of the question, this output does have the arn output.

Comment: Then you need `value = values(module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader)[*].arn`. But as I have mentioned in my first comment, it will be a list.

Comment: @MarkoE when I add .arn I get the following error 
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ../../modules/resource/lambda/dataLoaderLambda/output.tf line 2, in output "lambda_arn":
   2:   value = values(module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader)[*].arn

Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Comment: Ok, so that means you are not using `for_each` and I can see that now. Then what you need is `value = module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader.arn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the conversation from the comments, since the module is not invoked with `for_each`, outputs can be fetched with:

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = module.shared_services_lambda_data_loader.arn
}
```